# Keep getting NoSuchElementException and dont know how to fix it

Tags: java, oop

In my project, I need a menu that opens waits for input, gets the input and performs task
and opens the menu again. A simple Atm program helper. But I keep getting NoSuchElementException.
I can use any help. ( I dont want to open my scanner in main so I need somthing else)

```
public Operator(Account account, Operations op) {
        this.account = account;
        this.op = op;
    }

    public void operationSellect() {
        
        boolean c = true;
        
        while(c) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the operation number you want to do: ");
            System.out.println("1 : Show Ballance");
            System.out.println("2 : Withdraw cash");
            System.out.println("3 : Deposit Money");
            System.out.println("4 : Exit System");
            System.out.println("");
            sc.nextLine();
            String option = sc.nextLine();
            
            switch(option) {
            case "1":{
                op.showBalance(account);
                break;
            }
            case "2":{
                op.withdraw(account);
                break;
            }
            case "3":{
                op.deposit(account);
                break;
            }
            case "4":{
                c=false;
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("Entered a wrong character, please enter again");
                
            }
            }
            
    
    }
```

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
at ReadingPart.Operator.operationSellect(Operator.java:29)
at TransactionPart.ATM.start(ATM.java:34)
at TransactionPart.Main.main(Main.java:18)


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(1234, "1234", 3000, 2);
    Card card = new Card("123456","Cash");
    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
    CardReader cardReader = new CardReader(account , card, messageService);
    PasswordController passwordController = new PasswordController(account, messageService);
    Operations operations = new Operations();
    Operator operator = new Operator(account, operations);
    
    
    
    
    ATM atm = new ATM(cardReader, passwordController, messageService, operations, operator, account, card);
    
    
    
    atm.start();
    }
```

Where I controll the password taken from user

```
public class PasswordController {

private Account account;
private MessageService mesage;


public PasswordController(Account account, MessageService mesage) {
    this.account=account;
    this.mesage = mesage;
}

public boolean control() {
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);               //scanner scans password
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;           
    while(count<3) {                                    // count from 0 to 3 for 3 tries
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String password = sc1.nextLine();
        sc1.nextLine();
        if (password.equals(account.getPassword())) {   //checking if the password is correct
            System.out.println("Password is correct.");
            result = true;
            count=3;
            
        }
        else {
            mesage.badPassword();
            count++;
            
        }
    }
    if(result==false)                                   //person entered password 3 times and failed all 3
        System.out.println("3 wrong tries, card is now frozen. Please contact the bank");
    sc1.close();
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: what's the purpose of the singular `sc.nextLine(); before reading the `option``?

Comment: In fact, if you just remove that line I'm pretty sure your solution would work. Typo/Forgotten line?

Comment: @Rogue I saw it in a tutorial where if you try to get .nextLine() and .nextInt() ,or other way I dont remember right now, it gives an error too so by adding a null next line solves that problem. I thought that was the problem but gives me the same error when I delete it.

Comment: @f1sh I tried that way too. Gives NoSuchElement again.

Comment: So the problem you're describing is if you call `#nextInt` for numbers separated by newlines, then the subsequent `#nextInt` call will not find a number because `'\n` is in the way. Thus, to fix that you would call `#nextLine` _after_ the `#nextInt` call (The problem isn't the numbers, it's the way they're read!). In this case, however, you are simply reading `#nextLine` from the get-go, so there aren't erroneous newlines in your input to account for. In other words, since you aren't reading them as ints (but instead as strings), you only need the single `#nextLine`.

Comment: I somehow doubt that the Exception comes from this code. IIRC `String option = sc.nextLine();` blocks until enter is is pressed, returning at least an empty `String`. Can you include the stacktrace please?

Comment: @Rogue yeah I thought that way too but I just wanted to try if it will solve it or not but it gives NoSuchElement other way too. I dont get it.

Comment: @f1sh included it

Comment: @2brk if you're using a piped stdin (i.e. `java -jar myProgram.jar < someInputFile.txt`) then I could see this happening, but from a plain command line input you would not get that exception with this currently posted code (it would just wait for you to enter something else). Either post the code causing the exception _in addition to_ the full stack trace / error you see, or run this code again and see the latest results.

Comment: Oh, you know what, I've got a better guess. Did you do `new Scanner(System.in)` elsewheres in your code? If one of those scanners is closed, you'll close `System.in` and then be unable to read it anymore. For `System.in` specifically, it's recommended to keep a "global" `Scanner` for it. I'd include the full code for ATM, Main, and Operator for confirmation. The very `Scanner` in `Operator` is already malformed: you're making a new `Scanner` every iteration of the loop! Definitely pull that out into a field, potentially even a `static` field (a rare recommendation for mutable fields).

Comment: @Rogue Yes there are other scanner in my classes I will update it right now.

Comment: @Rogue so what can I do to not close the System.in ?

Comment: @Rogue Yes, in every class I closed the scanner . After I dleted the scanners' .close() methods my code works just fine. Thanks for the help. But now I think about it, doesn't unclosed scanners cause me problems?

Comment: Absolutely, they'll become quite a bloat on your program's resources, and will possibly not be automatically garbage collected. There are more proper ways of managing `Scanner` (having dedicated classes for interfacing with stdin/other inputs, or abstracting away the notion of reading input entirely in one submodule), but overall for a small program keeping a `private static final Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);` which you can allow access to elsewheres (or even expose just the `#nextLine` method from a class) will suffice. The main point is you really just want the one unclosed object